# what is $ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{cos(x)-1}{8x^3-6x^2} $

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to calculate it using LHopital's rule and got $\frac{1}{12}$, however, symbolab says its infinity

Comment: $\frac{1}{12}$ is correct

Comment: $\cos(x)=1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^4)$. The limit is following...

Answer (score 4):

The numerator is in essence $-\frac12 x^2 + O(x^4)$ as $\cos x = 1 - \frac12 x^2 + O(x^4)$, the denominator is $x^2(8x-6)$, so
the fraction is (cancelling the $x^2$ in both terms) $$\frac{-\frac12 +O(x^2)}{(8x-6)}$$ So the limit as $x \to 0$ will be clear now...

Comment: a sign in expansion of $\cos$ is wrong

Comment: You meant $1-\frac 12 \cos^2 x +O(x^4)$ of course.

Comment: @Deepak corrected my expansion..